# Evaluate and simplify: $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin 2x}{3x}$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, trigonometry

> Evaluate and simplify:
>   $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin 2x}{3x}$$

So, by direct substitution, it is indeterminate. I got the derivative of this functio,n and now I'm going around in circles with the trig identities.

Is there a more efficient way of solving this?

Comment: Have you heard of l'hopital rule? $\lim_{x \to a} \frac {f(x)}{g(x)}=lim_{x \to a} \frac {f'(x)}{g'(x)}$. Use this and you'll get the answer of $2/3$

Comment: Use $\lim_{x\to0}{\sin{2x}\over2x}=1$

Comment: $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2\sin 2x}{3.2x}$    Now ,$\lim_{x\to0}{\sin{2x}\over2x}=1$ so the given limit is $2/3$

Comment: Thank you! I had no idea about the l'hopital rule to be honest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use L'Hôpital's rule

Differentiate both sides

$$\lim_{x\to 0}  \frac {2\cos {2x}}{3}$$

Put $x=0$

$\cos {(2*0)}=1$

$$\lim_{x\to 0}  \frac {2\cos {2x}}{3}=   \frac {2}{3}$$

Answer (score 4):

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin 2x}{3x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{\sin 2x}{2x}=\frac{2}{3}\cdot\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin 2x}{2x}=\frac{2}{3}$$

Answer (score 3):

*Hint:* Note that the function $$\frac{\sin y}{y}$$ has a limiting value of $1$ as $y$ vanishes.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use the identity
$$
\sin 2x=2\sin x\cos x
$$
whence
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin 2x}{3x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2\sin x\cos x}{3x}=\frac{2}{3}
\left(\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)\left(\lim_{x\to 0}\cos x\right)=\frac{2}{3}\times 1\times 1=\frac{2}{3}$$
where we used the limit laws in conjunction with the well-known fact that
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1
$$
as well as the fact that cosine is a continuous function.

Answer (score 0):

Apply L'Hôpital's rule ([https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27Hôpital%27s_rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule)).

We have $lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{sin2x}{3x} =lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{2cos2x}{3}=\frac{2}{3}.$

One more approach that you may apply using the sine series($Sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{3}+\ldots$) and then apply the limit $x\rightarrow 0$, you will get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Use L'Hospital's Rule:

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin(2x)}{3x}$$
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{2\cos(2x)}{3}$$
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{2*1}{3}$$
$$\frac{2}{3}$$